# Laravel 5.4 : get parent object from the child object using Model Inheritance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4.

The issue I am facing is regarding model inheritance.

Following is the code snippet of the 2 classes:

```
class Company extends Model{
protected $table = 'companies';
}

class Vendor extends Company{
protected $table = 'companies';
}
```

NOTE : Here the **Company is the parent class** and **Vendor is the child class**. Also, both the models refer to the same table.

I am having an object of the **Vendor** class (i.e. child class).

For example:

```
$vendor = Vendor::find(1);
```

How can I get the Company object from the existing Vendor object?
As both refer to the same record in the database.

Comment: The `$vendor` object is also an instance of `Company` class because it extends the `Company` class. If you need to access any method from parent then you can use `parent::method()`. What is your requirement exactly?

Comment: @TheAlpha, I need to cast the vendor object to the **Company** type. One such requirement is during **instanceof** validation.

Comment: `$vendor instanceof Company` is `true`.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? What is your exact issue?

Comment: @TheAlpha .. I have a belongsToMany relation in the **Company** class. But, when I try to use that relation using the **Vendor** object . I get an error saying **column not found**. This is because laravel is trying to find a column name **vendor_id** according to its convention. But, the actual column name is **company_id**. That's why I need the **Company** object and NOT the **Vendor** object.

Comment: You can specify the `key`, post your relationship method declaration here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by specifying field/column names in your relationship method. You can specify the exact keys when you declare the relationship method so `Laravel` will not use it's convention for mapping the model/table, for example, you can use the following syntax in your `Company` model for it's `many-to-many` relationship method:

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'App\OtherModel', // name of the other model
            'pivot_table_name', // name of the pivot table
            'company_id' // this model foreign key
            'other_model_foreign_key' // other model foreign key
        );
    }
}
```

In thus case, the foreign keys should match with the field/column names used in your pivot table. Now you can call your relationship method (`someMethod`) from instance of `Vendor` objects and it'll work just fine because `compoany_id` is specified so `Laravel` will use that column name instead of `vendor_id`. Check more about [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).